# How do you disable jquerymobile on one page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I created a new HTML page in my site that has no jquerymobile code in it. This page is a contract where I need to specifically set font sizes and types and I don't want jquerymobile to change the theme. It has to look a very specific way.

However, it seems like jquerymobile still has control of it, even if I just navigate directly to the page. I say this because I am trying to load a CSS stylesheet into the page like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/contract.css">
```

However whenever I view the source of the page, it shows like this:

```
<style>body,td,p{font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif}p.breakhere{page-break-before:always}td{font-size:14px;margin:0;padding:0}p{font-size:9px}</style>
```

Basically it shows the contents of the css file. Also it seems to be caching the same css file. I'm assuming jquerymobile is somehow doing this but I'm not sure how. Anyone know what might be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. The server had Google Pagespeed installed that was causing the caching.